# Can use .png images but not .jpg images in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two images in my assets/images folder in Ruby On Rails when I use:

```
<%= image_tag("photo.png") %>
```

in my view, the image displays fine on the page.

When I use:

```
<%= image_tag("photo2.jpg") %>
```

I get nothing.  Does anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Do you have `photo2.jpg` in `assets/images` folder?

Comment: ^ likely what Pavan just said

Comment: @Pavan yes I do have it

Comment: What is your OS? If your are using linux to develop or deploy, attention to upper and lower cases of file name.

Comment: Check in your chrome dev tool in elements, you can find the compiled path of the image. Compare it against the working one.

Comment: Try `rake assets:precompile` before starting the rails server.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to be a problem with the case even though i'm on windows